# Display Cursor In An VB ActiveX TextBox

Tags: vb6, ms-word

I have the following code for an existing Word 2007 form which my companby uses and i have been asked to see if i can add the cusror to display in a ActiveX TextBox when its enabled.

There is on question on the form which has 3 OptionButtons and 2 TextBoxes and depending on the radio button select will enable the relevent TextBox but i can seem to get a cursor displayed in the TextBox when it's enabled.

There are various other TextBoxes on the form all of which are ArctiveX so i dont think i can use it on the 'Load', or can i?

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()

If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
TextBox1.Enabled = False
TextBox2.Enabled = False
TextBox1.BackColor = &HE0E0E0
TextBox2.BackColor = &HE0E0E0
TextBox1.Text = Empty
TextBox2.Text = Empty
End If

End Sub

----------------------------------------------

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()

If OptionButton2.Value = True Then
TextBox1.Enabled = True
TextBox2.Enabled = False
TextBox1.BackColor = &HFFFFFF
TextBox2.BackColor = &HE0E0E0
TextBox2.Text = Empty
End If

End Sub

----------------------------------------------

Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()

If OptionButton3.Value = True Then
TextBox1.Enabled = False
TextBox2.Enabled = True
TextBox1.BackColor = &HE0E0E0
TextBox2.BackColor = &HFFFFFF
TextBox1.Text = Empty
End If

End Sub

----------------------------------------------

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub

----------------------------------------------

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correct then, It ll solve your problem

```
TextBox1.Enabled = True
TextBox1.SetFocus
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have tried using what you suggested under the TextBox1_Change() but the 'TextBox1.SetFocus' causes an error.  I also tried adding to an 'If' but that still doesnt work.

Comment: place TextBox1.SetFocus on OptionButton2_Click()

Comment: Thanks for the update but it still doesn't work.  i get a debug error when making my selection

Answer (score 0):

You need to Activate the textbox, e.g.

```
TextBox1.Activate
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Works exaclty how i needed but when the "TextBox2.Enabled = False" the cursor is still displayed in the last 'Active' field.  Is there a way to stop this as i only want the cursor to be displayed when "TextBox2.Enabled = True"